# loop through variables passed to some method as parameters

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, string-comparison

it's my first time to use this kind of action ...using a loops with methods and stuff like that.

i would like to be able to loop through all parameters passed to `ExcludeUsers()`

say i have a few string type values ,

```
string user1 = "Anna";
string user2 = "Brenda";
string user3 = "John";
string user4 = "Warren";


      public bool ExcludeUsers(string OmittedUser1, string OmittedUser2, string OmittedUser3)
      {
          string userName = "John";


          //  i want to loop through all parameters passed in ...
          //  something like this 
          foreach (string param in params)
          {
              if(userName ==  param)
                return false;
          }
          return true;
     }
```

then i want to be able using

```
if(ExcludeUsers(user1, user2, user3))
//do some work
```

Comment: you want to be able to loop through all strings passed?
is that all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then you should pass it in  as OmittedUsers[],  an `Array` of `string` values instead

```C#
public bool ExcludeUsers(string[] OmittedUsers)
{
          string userName = "John";

          bool ConditionMet = true;

              foreach (string userToOmmit in OmittedUsers)
              {
                  ConditionMet =  string.Compare(userName, userToOmmit) == 0;

                          if (ConditionMet)
                          return false;
              }

    return ConditionMet;
}
```

Then you might want to use it like This:

```C#
if(ExcludeUsers(new string[]
                           {
                                user1,
                                user2,
                                user3,
                                user4
                           }
               )
  )
{

//do some work here...

}
```

you also want to consider if the `string`s that you try to compare 
will also (might) have capital letters,

so you should be using `.ToLower()` when comparing string values 
in general ..

though it really depends if the string should be case sensitive.

for example

if the scenario is that "abc" is valid being "ABC" or "Abc" (meaning your `string` is case **Insensitive**)

then you should, in that case the use :

```
//when "abc" = "ABC" is valid (case Insensitive)
ConditionMet =  string.Compare(userName.ToLower(), userToOmmit.ToLower())== 0;
```

if string values should be case sensitive :

```
//if the string "abc" = "Abc" is NOT the same for you, then
ConditionMet =  string.Compare(userName, userToOmmit) == 0;
```

which in your case seem to me that a username **is** case sensitive

... so you know your options.

Comment: thank you for this good, well explained and generous answer ! i forgot the issue of using `string` arrays ..(P

Answer (score 1):

Change the method's signature to:

```
public bool ExcludeUsers(params string[] omittedUsers)
```

Then iterate the parameters through a `foreach` loop.